# jQuery: validate before submitting

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, form-submit

I'm trying to validate my form before submitting it. I'm trying it with this code below, but it always submit the form values:

```
$('#gestione_profilo').submit(function () {

    $("#gestione_profilo").validate({

        rules: {

            'person_data[document_number]': "required"

        },

        messages: {

            'person_data[document_number]': "required"

        }

    });


    form_data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({

        url: "<?php echo url_for('profile/index') ?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        success: function() { $("#forma_profile").unmask(); }

        });

        $("#forma_profile").mask("Aggiornando dati...");

        return false;

    });
```

Any help?

Regards

Javier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) in your `document.ready` handler, since it *sets up* validation (and on a `submit` event that's already run here) it doesn't *run* validation.  It should look like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#gestione_profilo").validate({
    rules: {
        'person_data[document_number]': "required"
    },
    messages: {
        'person_data[document_number]': "required"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
      $.post("<?php echo url_for('profile/index') ?>", $(form).serialize(), 
        function() { 
          $("#forma_profile").unmask();
      });
      $("#forma_profile").mask("Aggiornando dati...");
    }
  });
});
```

This involves *no* [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler added on the form itself (`.validate()` does this underneath), instead use the [`submitHandler` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) which runs only when the form is valid, `invalidHandler` is its counterpart, which runs when the form is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't unmask the form, nor load the values introduced.

Comment: @user248959 - "load the values introduced"...can you explain?