# Validate field, select or checkbox without form tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, validation, input

Good day,

I found a lot of topics about that, but, without a proper answer.

Many of topics ended with question why you just can't add form?

I'm working on a project that based on ASP.NET and I have one form tag, one form tag that contains all the html code inside it.

I can't use any ASP.NET controls and must done validation by front-end (jQuery).

Everything is fine when there is only one form and one submit button, then I can use simple query validation plugin, but it gets complicated when I have more than one form and of course more than one submit button.

For example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" id="form123">

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="form1">
<input id="field1 "type="text" />
<input id="submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>

<div id="form2">
<input id="field2" type="text" />
<input id="submit2" type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>

</div>

<form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion, ideas or real example how to do that?

Maybe I can somehow put every field and submit button inside a div and validate them by submit within that div?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post your code please

Comment: I added simple example, asp.net always wrap everything inside on form, so i need to validate filed1 by clicking submit1 and etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use specific classes or ids on the elements you need to validate separately.

so it will end up looking something like:

```
<form>

    <input id="myFirstField" />

    <button id="myFirstButton">First Button</button>

    <input id="mySecondField" />

    <button id="mySecondButton">Second Button</button>

</form>
```

and then using whatever your validation plugin you can do things like:

```
$('#myFirstButton')click(function(){

     $('#myFirstField').validate("whatever");

});
```

and do conditional things, etc etc

Comment: I tried that, even tried with .live('click', fn), but its not working.

Comment: my apologies mate this problem is more complex then i realized. check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255988/jquery-validate-before-submitting