# jquery form validation for formvalidation plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying lot to get it work but no luck..any jquery expert can share there view please.

i have form, for validation i use form validation plugin (jquery) which doese validation correctly when i put.

```
$("#contact").validationEngine();  // #contact is my form id.
```

now i want to submit the form using ajax on button click (submit form button) which is also happening correctly using following.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
 ajax code goes here ...
}
```

here problem is when i click on submit button it goes and update database it does not wait for formvalidation plugin to validate it...

what actually i want to do is first validate the form if all okay then go and call ajax function to update the database. if validation fails then dont call ajax function to update data base.

could any one please share some clues.

Thank you in advance...

regards, Mona.

Comment: where are you running your validation???? in document.ready handler???

Comment: yes it is in document ready handler

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
   $("#contact").validate({
     rules: {

     },
    submitHandler: function(form){
  ajax call
    }
 });
});
```

orignal post [jQuery: validate before submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255988/jquery-validate-before-submitting)  try if this helps to resolve your issue..

Comment: Scorpio.. thank you for answer..but no this is not going to work.. i already have validationEngine() function which takes care of all validation..i just want to make sure that ajax form should submit after it passes all validation in this validationEngine() function.

Comment: hmmm so what goes wrong when you use $("#contact").validationEngine(); instead of $("#contact").validate.. and use a submitHandler as above...just give it a try..